# Can I migrate a partitioned table to a non-partitioned table in Oracle with the CREATE TABLE statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, partitioning, data-partitioning, ora2pg

I have an Oracle 11g partitioned table with 10 partitions for ten years of data, each on its own tablespace partitioned by range. Each year-partition contains 12 monthly-partitions.

I would like to convert this table to a non-partitioned table, before migrating all the database to Postgresql 10.7 with ora2pg.

I've read that I could first backup this table by expdp and then import it using PARTITIONS_OPTIONS parameter option of impdp.

But is it also possible to use this following statement as a strict equivalent ?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS non_partitioned_table AS SELECT * FROM partitioned_table
```

I would not lose any data, but what about the indexes ?

Is there other differences between these two procedures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax you posted doesn't exist in Oracle (there's no `if not exists` clause there).

Therefore, you'd

```
create table non_partitioned_table as select * from partitioned_table;
```

If object whose name is `non_partitioned_table` already exists, that command would fail.

---

No indexes would be created *automatically* - you'd have to create them manually, but - you'd do that in PostgreSQL anyway, wouldn't you? Why bother in Oracle as you won't be using that table for anything (except migration purposes); right?

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. Do you see any other difference ? I'm writing a script-shell to do the migration and the create statement seems simpler than the expdp/impdp method.

Comment: Data pump (expdp / impdp) work in Oracle only. I don't think you can import that .DMP file into PostgreSQL, so ... there's no point in considering it at all. At least, that's what I think.

Comment: I would datapump in Oracle before migrating with ora2pg to Postgresql.

Comment: OK, but - why? You'd have the same data in two tables already: partitioned table, and non-partitioned table. There's nothing wrong in keeping it in a dump file, though, so - if you want, go for it - export it.

Comment: The question is not really about the data, but about the data-partitioning. I take advantage of the migration to remove the data-partitioning of this table. Method 1: expdp table + impdb table with PARTITION_OPTIONS=merge  + ora2pg. Method 2 : create table non_partitioned + drop table partitioned + ora2pg. I will try method 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use expdp to export the PARTITION table.

Then use impdp with the MERGE option to import it back into a non partition table. How you get the data into postgres is up to you.

```
expdp TABLES=scott.part_tab USERID="' / as sysdba'" DIRECTORY=test_dir DUMPFILE=part_tab.dmp LOGFILE=part_tab.log


impdp USERID="'/ as sysdba'" TABLES=scott.part_tab DIRECTORY=test_dir DUMPFILE=part_tab.dmp LOGFILE=imp_part_tab.log REMAP_SCHEMA=scott:testuser
```